# Datatables button through React App

Tags: reactjs, datatables

I've been having issues trying to add an excel export button when working in React. I assume it has something to do with an import but I can't find much help online related to React and DataTables.net in this regard. I just want a user to be able to download to excel.

these are my imports related to jquery and datatables

```
const $ = require('jquery');
$.DataTable = require('datatables.net');
import 'datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css'
```

here is where the table is defined. It works except for the buttons

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    this.$el.DataTable({
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
          data: this.makeArray(),
          columns: this.getColumns(),
          pageLength:this.props.json.length,
          buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'Save current page',
                    fileName:  "data.xlsx",
                    exportOptions: {
                       modifier: {
                            page: 'current'
                           }
                    }
                 }]});
}
```

this is the render method

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <table className="display" width="100%" ref={el=>this.el=el} />
        </div>);
}
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answered my own question

needed to do install jzip, require it and then attach it to the window object

```
const jzip = require( 'jzip');
window.JSZip = jzip;
```

I also switched the button to excelhtml5. Here are all the jquery/datatable imports I have

```
const $ = require('jquery');
$.DataTable = require('datatables.net');
import 'datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css'
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min' );
const jzip = require( 'jzip');
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min' );
import 'datatables.net-buttons-dt/css/buttons.dataTables.css'

window.JSZip = jzip;
```

here is the updated buttons portion of the componentDidMount method.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    this.$el.DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
            data: this.makeArray(),
            columns: this.getColumns(),
                paging:false,
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5'
    ]
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: hello, i was able to follow your code and enable the excel button as well. would you know how to enable the other buttons such as pdf and column visibility?

Answer (score 0):

Following the bvmcode answer I've been able to solve the problem, but instead of use requires I'm only using imports. To know what imports and components to install: https://datatables.net/download/

My imports:

```
import * as jzip from 'jszip';
import 'pdfmake';
import 'datatables.net-dt';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-dt';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js';
import 'datatables.net-fixedheader-dt';
import 'datatables.net-rowgroup-dt';
window.JSZip = jzip;
```