# Jquery Datatable Buttons Not Showing Up On React js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datatables

I initialized Jquery Datatables in my react app and it works perfectly fine, except that the buttons aren't showing up.
Here's my code:

I tried this at first and it works but it doesn't display the buttons.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import JSZip from 'jszip';
window.JSZip = JSZip;

import 'datatables.net-bs4';
import 'datatables.net-responsive';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print';
```

Next, I tried the code below as well, the error it throws didn't allow my react app to render. It complained about this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined
    at DataTable`

```
import $ from 'jquery';
const JSZip = require('jszip');
window.JSZip = JSZip;

require('datatables.net')();
require('datatables.net-responsive')();
require('datatables.net-buttons')();
require('datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis')();
require('datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5')();
require('datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print')();
```

Finally, how I initialize my datatable:

```
var table = $('#dynamic_table').DataTable({
          'lengthChange': false,
          'buttons': [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis' ],
});
table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#dynamic_table_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
```

I came across a similar question [Datatables button through React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618168/datatables-button-through-react-app), but it didn't solve my problem. 
Without the buttons to export into excel the whole purpose of my using this plugin is defeated. Can I get a little help?

Comment: Is the HTML #dynamic_table actually visible before the DataTable Initialisation ?

Comment: well no. I set it to initialise on component will mount

Comment: I have had issue with those buttons (not appearing) in the past if the table was not actually visible (well not hidden) when doing the Initialisation.. I had display:none all worked fine but when brought in buttons it did not work. Maybe just try to ensure the underlying HTML table is visible 1st ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import JSZip from 'jszip';
window.JSZip = JSZip;

import 'datatables.net-bs4';
import 'datatables.net-responsive';
import 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash';
import 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print';
```

After importing all my dependencies, it was as simple as adding

```
"dom": 'Bfrtip'
```

to my datatable initialization.

```
$("#dynamic_table").DataTable({
  "lengthChange": true,
  "dom": 'Bfrtip',
  "buttons": [
    'copyHtml5',
    'excelHtml5',
    'csvHtml5',
    'pdfHtml5'
  ]
});
```

I got rid of this line

```
table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#dynamic_table_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
```

Comment: Did you managed to make pdf generation work?

Comment: My table displays the button, but nothing happens when I click it.